# TF state on gitlab ci

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, gitlab-ci

I am deploying an AWS infrastructure with terraform with gitlab ci.

after running init & plan, the terraform apply doesn't work.

the error is :

```
Error: Failed to persist state to backend.
```

The state of the TF is stored in the gitlab api folder, example link : https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/3232323/terraform/state/

However this state couldn't be modified, is there any way to make this work other than a terraform destroy command ?

The terraform apply command however, works fine locally

Here some details of the .gitlab-ci.yml file :

```
apply_www:
  stage: deploy
#  environment:
#    name: production
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}/devel/www
    - terraform init
    - terraform apply -lock=false -input=false $PLAN 
  dependencies:
    - plan_www
  artifacts:
    name: source_code
    paths:
      - ${TF_ROOT}/devel/www/dist/source.zip
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: Let me just check if I understood you correctly: you are saving terraform state file to a directory on Gitlab?

Comment: yes exactly, it's a gitlab managed terraform state: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/

Comment: Very nice, I wasn't aware of this feature. Could you provide more information in your question, i.e. the steps from the `.gitlab-ci.yaml`?

Comment: yes just added the details

Comment: Can you share your state configuration as well please? Also if there's any more context surrounding that state locking error that might be helpful because it sounds potentially environmental.